# Async Request Function with Protractor

Tags: javascript, async-await, protractor

- Node Version: *v6.10.3*;
- Protractor Version: *Version 5.1.2*;
- Browser(s): *IE*;
- Operating System and Version: *Windows 10*;
- Description: **I am testing an Angular page using Protractor. But, during tests, I also need to validate a request using POST (API REST). But, I need get tokenId for later send GET with token authentication**.

So, I have the following codes:

*protractor.conf.js*

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'mocha',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('serenity-js'),
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['vmiRest.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
    chromeOptions : {
      args : ["incognito"],
      prefs: {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    }
  },
  mochaOpts: {
    reporter: "spec",
    slow: 12000,
    timeout: 20000,
    ui: 'bdd'
  },
  serenity: {
    dialect: 'mocha'
  }
}
```

*vmiRest.js*:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var SecurityApi = require(__dirname + '/common/restSecurityApi.js');
var Parts = require(__dirname + '/common/restParts.js');
describe('VMI - API', function() {
  var tokenId = 'none';
  var username = 'bla';
  var password = '*';
  var dealer = '112571';
  var part = '0420665R1';
beforeEach(function () {
    //
  });
it('Get Token from SecurityApi', function() {
    //
    var restSecurityApi= new SecurityApi(username, password);
    restSecurityApi.getToken(function (tokenId) {
      assert.notEqual(tokenId, null);
      console.log(tokenId);
    });
  });
  it('Test Interface getStockFullUsingGET', function() {
    console.log(tokenId);
  });
});
```

*restSecurityApi.js*:

```
var request = require('request');
var SecurityApi = function (username, password) {
  this.getToken = function (callback) {
    var headers = {
      'X-OpenAM-Username': username,
      'X-OpenAM-Password': password,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    // Configure the request
    var options = {
        url: 'https://appsqa.host/SecurityApi/Token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    }
    // Start the request
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var tokenId = json["tokenId"];
            callback(tokenId);
        }  else {
            callback(null);
        }
    })
  };
};
module.exports = SecurityApi;
```

During execution, the request function return the result/response **LATE** (async), when the test ended! So, how can I execute request sync or respecting the order of execution?

I used promise, asyn/await, but nothing works! Please, I need a help! Thank you very much!

**NEW**: I also tested as following:

*vmiRest.js*:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var SecurityApi = require(__dirname + '/common/restSecurityApi.js');
var Parts = require(__dirname + '/common/restParts.js');
describe('AGCOnline - VMI - API', function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  var tokenId = 'none';
  var username = 'user';
  var password = '*';
  var dealer = '11571';
  var part = '040665R1';
  it('Get Token from SecurityApi', function() {
    tokenId = SecurityApi.getToken(username, password);
    console.log(tokenId);
  });
  it('Test Interface getStockFullUsingGET (BKW11)', function() {
    console.log(tokenId);
  });
});
```

*restSecurityApi.js*:

```
var request = require('request');
exports.getToken = function (username, password) {
  var headers = {
    'X-OpenAM-Username': username,
    'X-OpenAM-Password': password,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  // Configure the request
  var options = {
    url: 'https://appsqa.agcoonline.com.br/SecurityApi/Token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
  }
  // Start the request
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      var tokenId = json["tokenId"];
        console.log(tokenId);
        return tokenId;
      }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  })
};
```

Even so, the same problem!

Comment: Don't you need to make the test asynchronous?

Comment: I don't need. But @Bergi, I tried without callback but I could not.

Comment: I meant you should try *with* a callback in the `it` test.

Comment: Why not use [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request) instead of request? That will make your live a lot easier

Comment: Solved! I used sync-request! Thank you very much @wswebcreation and Bergi.